Blazor Wasm JWT Authentication Issue .net 8
I have a .net 8 Blazor Wasm app which I am trying to add basic custom JWT authorisation to. (Users in our own db)
However when I go to the protected page it just shows screen with a 401 error. If I remove the authorize attribute the page works fine (although obviously not protected).
Here is the page
@page "/test"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@inject HttpClient Http
@attribute [Authorize]
<h3>Test</h3>

@code {

}

and the Routes.razor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <h1>Not authorized</h1>
            </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

and the Custom Authentication Provider
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Web.Client.Auth
{
    public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
        private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
        private readonly AuthenticationState _anonymous;
        private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;


        public CustomAuthStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage, NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;
            _anonymous = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
            _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
        }
        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                return _anonymous;
            }
            var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>(), "jwtAuthType"));

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            //CheckTimeSinceLogin(claims);
            return new AuthenticationState(claims);
        }

        public void NotifyUserAuthentication(string email)
        {
            var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email) }, "jwtAuthType"));
            var authState = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser));
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
        }
        public void NotifyUserLogout()
        {
            var authState = Task.FromResult(_anonymous);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authState);
        }
    }
}

Here is the Program.cs for the client app
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using RecoWeb.Client.Auth;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("VLA.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
await builder.Build().RunAsync();

and for the server app
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MyApp.DataService;
using MyApp.DataService.Models;
using MyApp.Interfaces;
using MyApp.Services;
using MyApp.Shared.Dtos;
using MyAppWeb.Client.Auth;
using MyAppWeb.Client.Pages;
using MyAppWeb.Components;
using MyAppWeb.Controllers;
using StockDataImporter;
using System.Text;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.local.json", optional: true);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();
builder.Services.AddControllers(); // Add this line
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var jwtSettings = config.GetSection("JWTSettings");
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = jwtSettings["validIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = jwtSettings["validAudience"],
        ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings["securityKey"]))
    };
});
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RecodbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataService, DataService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStockDataImportService, StockDataImportService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPartService, PartService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStockService, StockService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting(); // Add this line
app.UseAntiforgery();
app.UseAuthorization(); // Add this line
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(RecoWeb.Client._Imports).Assembly);
app.Run();

And I have the render mode set like this
<Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender: false)" />

What am I doing wrong?
Just to be clear, I am expecting the page to show the NotAuthorised content from the routes.razor.
It was never this hard in .net 7...

Here's a similar issue

However when I go to the protected page it just shows screen with a
401 error

Check your browser if it send a http request which was blocked by your authentication middleware on server side
You may try set interactivewebassembly render mode for entire app and navigate to your target page with Navigation manager
Last but not least,the engineering design of Blazor WebAssembly uses OAuth and OIDC as the best option for authentication in Blazor WebAssembly apps,token based authentication is not recommanded,you may read the document for more details

Thanks, I will give that a go. OAuth is not an option for this particular project due to the customer requirements.

So yes, it works if I go to the page via a nav link. Which is great thanks. However how do I stop it from breaking when someone goes directly to the link?

You could redirect users to some page else,such as login page when they send a http request directly to protected page,you could add related logic in authentication middleware or your custom middleware on server side
